# Try Catch Exception in Python (Similar to Java)

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I'm pretty new to Python overall, but I know Java pretty well. I am trying to use the exceptions in Python, but I'm not quite sure how they work.

In Java I would do this:

```java
try {
    //Code inside
} catch (Exception e) {
    continue;
}
```

How would I do something like this in Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: "_I am trying to use the exceptions in Python_" - Show us in the question what you have tried and what happened when you tried it. For more background on how to ask a good question, you can take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your own solution is correct Python, it is not quite the equivalent of the given Java code. Python's bare `except` catches all throwables (which extend from `BaseException` in Python), not just all exceptions. This includes things like `KeyboardInterrupt` (called by Ctrl+C) and `SystemExit`, which should almost never be caught.

The solution is to be as narrow as possible in defining the exception you catch. For instance, if you're converting a string to an integer but it might not be numeric, catch `ValueError`:

```python3
try:
    converted = int(string)
except ValueError:
    # handle the error
```

If you really want to catch any exception, use `except Exception:` rather than bare `except:`.

Answer (score 1):

All good I think I got it!

I can just use

```
try:
   #code here
except:
   continue
```

Comment: Note that you can also catch specific exceptions in Python (e.g., except Foo as f:)